# Returning an Array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have to finish a prompt tonight for my coding class, and I believe I am writing this incorrectly. I have reviewed other stackoverflow answers, but I still lack the understanding necessary to correctly solve this. This is part of a bigger project, so I have included all code in case another function is causing this error, but in my testing only the Ballot class is giving me errors.

> In getVote, if the parameter is within the used portion of the array,
> return the Voter pointer that corresponds with that position.

This is supposed to be tested with:

```
Ballot ballot1("WI-643UWO");
const Vote *vote3 = ballot1.getVote(2);
cout << vote3 << "\n";


//header file

pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Election {
private:
    string office;
    string firstCanidiateName;
    string secondCanidiateName;
public:
    Election(string office2, string firstCanidiateName2, string secondCanidiateName2);
    string getOffice() const;
    string getCandidate1() const;
    string getCandidate2() const;
};
class Vote {
private:
    string vOffice;
    string canidiateName;
    bool voteMadeInPerson;
public:
    Vote(string vOffice2, string canidiateName2, bool voteMadeInPerson2);
    string getOffice() const;
    string getCandidate() const;
    bool wasInPerson() const;
};
class Ballot {
private:
    string voterID;
    int votesStored;
    Vote* votePointer[6];
public:
    Ballot();
    Ballot(string voterID2);
    ~Ballot();
    string getVoterId() const;
    int getVoteCount() const;
    const Vote* getVote(int votePosition) const;
    void recordVote(string office, string candidateName, bool voteInPerson);
    int countInPersonVotes();
    int findVote(string office) const;
};

//functions file
#include "p3.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Election::Election(string office2, string firstCanidiateName2, string secondCanidiateName2) {
    office = office2;
    firstCanidiateName = firstCanidiateName2;
    secondCanidiateName = secondCanidiateName2;
}

string Election::getOffice() const {
    return office;
}
string Election::getCandidate1() const {
    return firstCanidiateName;
}
string Election::getCandidate2() const {
    return secondCanidiateName;
}
string Vote::getOffice() const {
    return vOffice;
}
string Vote::getCandidate() const {
    return canidiateName;
}
bool Vote::wasInPerson() const {
    return voteMadeInPerson;
}
Vote::Vote(string vOffice2, string canidiateName2, bool voteMadeInPerson2) {
    if (vOffice2.empty() == true) {
        vOffice2 = "Unknown";
    }
    vOffice = vOffice2;
    if (canidiateName2.empty() == true) {
        canidiateName2 = "Write In";
    }
    canidiateName = canidiateName2;
    voteMadeInPerson = voteMadeInPerson2;
}
string Ballot::getVoterId() const {
    return voterID;
}
int Ballot::getVoteCount() const {
    return votesStored;
}
const Vote* Ballot::getVote(int votePosition) const {
    Vote* out;
    if (votePosition > -1 && votePosition < votesStored) {
        //unsure if this is proper syntax -- will need testing
        out = votePointer[votePosition];
        return out;
    }
    else {
        out = nullptr;
        return out;
    }
}

void Ballot::recordVote(string office, string candidateName, bool voteInPerson) {
    if ((votesStored + 1) < 6) {
        int x = findVote(office);
        if (x != -1) {
            Vote* z = new Vote(office, candidateName, voteInPerson);
            votePointer[votesStored] = z;
            ++votesStored;
        }
    }
}
int Ballot::countInPersonVotes() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < votesStored; ++i) {
        bool x = false;
        x = votePointer[i]->wasInPerson();
        if (x == true) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int Ballot::findVote(string office) const {
    //test to make sure this logically works
    int i = 0;
    bool matchCheck = false;
    for (i = 0; i < votesStored; ++i) {
        if (votePointer[i]->getOffice() == office) {
            matchCheck = true;
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    if (matchCheck == false) {
        return -1;
    }
}
Ballot::Ballot(string voterID2) {
    voterID = voterID2;
    votesStored = 0;
}
Ballot::Ballot() {
    voterID = "Invalid ID";
    votesStored = 0;
}
Ballot::~Ballot() {
    /**this is what the prompt asks for, technically.
    the book details that this can be achieved in a more simple matter --
    using the delete[] operator.
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        delete votePointer[i];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated - I am unsure where I am messing up here. I seem to be getting a lot of read access violation errors, but we haven't touched on debugging, so I'm not necessarily sure how to identify what I did wrong. Furthermore, my functions did seem to work initially until I tried fixing it, and now it gives me a read-error almost instantly, which is concerning. And lastly - I am new to pointers, so there is a *very high chance* I messed up there. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The first, most important step, is to use an investigative process of elimination to determine where the problem originates.  You can use your debugger, or any combination of [debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  As currently written, you are having difficulty even describing the specific behavior of your program in response to input, let alone any indication that you have tried to find the problem.  Programs should be generally be written in small stages and tested at each stage.

Comment: I had a very quick skim-read of your program, and I notice that `votePointer` is never initialized, so you rely on `votesStored` to determine whether it contains a valid pointer.  But in `Ballot::~Ballot()` you call delete on everything, including any uninitialized values.  Either loop up to `votesStored` instead of `6`, or initialize the array to all `nullptr` in your constructor.

Comment: Since `votePointer` is an array of 6 pointers of type `Vote *`, and the function returns `votePointer[votePosition]`, the types match.   In other words, the function returns an element of `votePointer` with index `votePosition`.    Superficially, that looks correct, but it really depends on other functions setting elements of the array and variables that track how many are used (`voteStored`) are managed correctly- accessing elements that have not been initialised, or are outside the array gives undefined behaviour.